# How to capture "Print Tab" click event at the backstage in Outlook 2010 ?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, office-addins

I want to capture the click events in "TabPrint" at the backstage of outlook 2010.

Followint is what I have done so far

I have defined a custom UI in xml as following. I have directed every event to one method (which is OnPrintClick)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <commands>    
    <!-- Mail print related -->
    <command idMso="FilePrint" onAction="OnPrintClick"/>
    <command idMso="FilePrintCustomRange" onAction="OnPrintClick"/>
    <command idMso="FilePrintPreview" onAction="OnPrintClick"/>
    <command idMso="FilePrintQuick" onAction="OnPrintClick"/>
    <command idMso="GroupPrint" onAction="OnPrintClick"/>
    <command idMso="GroupPrintPreview" onAction="OnPrintClick"/>
    <command idMso="GroupPrintProtectedView" onAction="OnPrintClick"/>
    <command idMso="GroupPrintSettings" onAction="OnPrintClick"/>
    <command idMso="PrintCategory" onAction="OnPrintClick"/>
    <command idMso="PrintDialogAccess" onAction="OnPrintClick"/>
  </commands>
</customUI>
```

The OnPrintClick method is located in the `Connect` class in the solution. Following are the parameters which are accepted by this method.

```
 public void OnPrintClick(IRibbonControl control , ref bool cancel)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("PRINT !");
    }
```

When I execute this code, it does not capture any of the the click events which I have defined. Is there something that I am doing wrong here ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `command` tag will not play any role in case of backstage UI controls. You can repurpose only controls on the ribbon (not backstage). See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

A possible solution would be to consider hiding the built-in UI and rebuilding it fully with custom commands. Read more about the Backstage UI in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851(v=office.14).aspx#odc_office14_ta_CustomizeBackstageView_CreatingaFastCommandButton)
- [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691833(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Eugene. But how can we reprogram the existed functionality as it was before ?

Comment: Take a look at the articles I mentioned in the post first.