# Handling PowerPoint Save and SaveAs

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

It appears based on the few things I've found online that I need to rebuild PowerPoint's SaveAs backstage tab just so that I can find out if the user is trying to execute a SaveAs as opposed to a normal Save operation since PowerPoint events do not provide this information like Excel and Word does.

[How to Differentiate SaveAs call and Save call in PowerPoint events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336473/how-to-differentiate-saveas-call-and-save-call-in-powerpoint-events)

[How to capture "Print Tab" click event at the backstage in Outlook 2010 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837228/how-to-capture-print-tab-click-event-at-the-backstage-in-outlook-2010)

I've gone through the following articles.

[Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633(v=office.12).aspx)

[Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691833(v=office.14).aspx)

[Customizing the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851(v=office.14).aspx)

I have successfully removed the SaveAs Tab (TabSave) and replace it with my own button to trigger a SaveAs. Unfortunately by doing so I lose the other features on the SaveAs tab, such as saving to One Drive and Office 365 SharePoint which will annoy our customers.

Therefore, I've attempted to build the Tab again with no luck as the aforementioned stackoverflow articles suggest and I'm running into problems. I'm beginning to think it's not really possible. Am I on the right track? My ONLY objective here is to intercept SaveAs operations and be able to tell that it was a "SaveAs" and not a normal "Save".

Has anyone successfully done this? Is it even possible? If so, would you care to share your Custom UI XML?

Comment: If you repurpose the FileSaveAs command you should meet your objective. Is there any compelling reason to tamper the backstage?

Comment: Yes. I have repurposed FileSaveAs, but it's not enough. Per documentation above, you cannot repurpose backstage elements. You have to recreate them. Repurposing FileSaveAs does not repurpose the Save As functionality that is in the TabSave tab.

Comment: My bad. Could you elaborate on how you use the SaveAs repurpose? Do you do something before the dialog appears or after the Save completes?

Comment: Some people just set a boolean flag and execute the save as somehow. My requirements are different. I need to do some work on the file so I intend to totally repurpose it and implement the save myself. But I need to know that I need to prompt for a file name as opposed to saving to the existing file.

Comment: I don't see a way to make a full featured replacement for the 'Save As' backstage tab. Unless you want to degrade the user experience (which seems high handed) you will need to come up with an alternative workaround.

Comment: That's what I feared. All the posts I find suggest that is the solution to the lack of notification in power point events that the save was executed by a saveas. But I doubt anyone's actually pulled it off. I'm thinking a better alternative is to repurpose Save and flag that it's NON SaveAs and if flag doesn't exist assume it is SaveAs.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to my problem.

In Office 2013 they added as SaveAs tab. On that tab is a Save As button. It is impossible to repurpose that Save As button on a tab and it would appear it is not possible to replace the SaveAs tab as some have suggested without losing functionality.

But it is possible to repurpose FileSave reliably regardless if it's on BackStage or Ribbon.

```
<customUI
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"
    onLoad="CustomUiOnLoad" >
  <commands>
    <command idMso="FileSave" onAction="FileSave_OnAction" />
  </commands>
</customUI>
```

When FileSave_OnAction is called, set a flag in your document wrapper to signal where the save came from.

```
public void FileSave_OnAction(Office.IRibbonControl control, bool cancelDefault)
{
    using (var document = new ComWrapper<PowerPoint.Presentation>(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation))
    using (var docWrapper = DocWrapper<PowerPoint.Presentation>.GetWrapper(document))
    {
        try
        {
            cancelDefault = true;
            docWrapper.SaveAsUI = false;
            docWrapper.Save();
        }
        finally
        {
            docWrapper.SaveAsUI = true;
        }
    }
}
```